# Sort PostgreSQL JSONB object by object key's value

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb-api

Given the following JSON (or JSONB) object:

```json
{"apple": 13.1, "banana": 2.0, "zucchini": 7.2, "orange": 19.1}
```

I would like to sort the object keys by their values and get this instead:

```json
{"banana": 2.0, "zucchini": 7.2, "apple": 13.1, "orange": 19.1}
```

How do I do that using PostgreSQL 14 and its JSON/JSON-B features?

Comment: `json` can hold an arbitrary order of keys but `jsonb` deduplicates and [reorders the keys internally](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html). You will need `json` and you will need to construct it based on a reordered `json(b)_each()` of the input value.

Comment: Sure, but that does not answer the question unfortunately. Even if I use `json` instead of `jsonb`, it is still not clear how to re-order based on property values.

Comment: Sorry for the wait. I posted the comment just to give a hint before posting an answer with doc links and a demo.

Comment: No worries, I just exhausted all my options (using aggregates, building a json object, sorting using `->1`), none of them worked sadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `json` can hold an arbitrary order of keys but `jsonb` deduplicates and [**reorders** the keys internally](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html). That means you will need `json` and you will need to construct it based on a reordered [`json(b)_each_text()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.5.1.1.1) of the input value, which you need to aggregate back into [`json_object_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.15.1.1.1), internally [ordering](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) it by values: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yn9kCBfL)

```sql
select json_object_agg(k,v order by v::numeric)
from my_table
cross join json_each_text(jdata) as j(k,v)
group by my_table.ctid;
```

| json_object_agg |
| --- |
| { "banana" : "2.0", "zucchini" : "7.2", "apple" : "13.1", "orange" : "19.1" } |

I don't know your primary key, so to re-construct each json(b) value in your desired order I grouped them by [system column `ctid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html#DDL-SYSTEM-COLUMNS-CTID), which I could rely on being always present and unique.

Comment: If the example was just an example and your values are a bit more complex mix of *stuff*, you can use custom [collations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#COLLATION-CONCEPTS) to order the *stuff* alphabetically, when it's mostly text, and still respect numerical values when they appear on their own or as a part of the text.

Comment: Woah, this is awesome. This worked for me. But I am not sure why cross join is needed. Could you explain why we are using `cross join` here?

Comment: Also, FYI, it works with `jsonb` too by using `jsonb_each_text` and converting `jdata` to `jsonb` via `jdata::jsonb`. I needed `jsonb` specifically to get rid of some columns that are not needed via `-{a,b,c}::text[]` which will remove columns `a`,`b`, and `c`.

Comment: `jsonb` offers a superset of `json` functions and operators, so most of the time anything you can do to a `json` you can also do to a `jsonb`, just more ways and usually faster. The `join` type doesn’t really matter because the `_each_text` is a set-returning function entirely dependent on each row of `my_table`. I usually trade it for a `,` comma for brevity, but the SQL crowd is pretty sensitive about the old, implicit `join` syntax.